# C2079 in C++ programm

Tags: c++, header, include

I try to understand how compiling/linking in C++ works. So I created a simple test project which hast the following form:

**A.h**

```
class A {
  public:
   int a;
   A() { a = 3; }
};
```

**B.h**

```
#include "A.h"
class B {
   private:
     A myA;
};
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h" 
#include "B.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
  A myA;
  B myB;
  cout << myA.a;
}
```

If I try to compile this I get an C2011 (class type redefinition). This is clear for me because B.h includes A.h as well and my Main would look like:

```
class A { ...} // through include of A.h in Main.cpp 
class A { ...} 
// through include of B.h in Main.cpp which includes A.h as.    
// well causes the redefinition error

int main() { ... }
```

But why is also a C2079 error

```
'B::myA' uses undefined class 'A'
```

in B.h? So if I include the A.h the class definition of A should be inserted an B.h should look like

```
class A { ... }  
class B {
   private:
     A myA;  
};
```

WHY is class A not defined in B.h? Class should be available through include of A.h (if I remove the include of A.h in Main.cpp it works without problems)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Answer (score 0):

main include A and B. B include A => main include A twice. Use `ifndef`. Where `_UNIQ_FILE_NAME_` is `A_H` and `B_H` for example

```
#ifndef _UNIQ_FILE_NAME_
#define _UNIQ_FILE_NAME_
// Content here
#endif // _UNIQ_FILE_NAME_
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I try to compile this I get an C2011 (class type redefinition). This is clear for me because B.h includes A.h as well

So, if it's clear why you have the error why don't you fix it? Usually you should use [header guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) to ensure that they are included only once:

```
#ifndef A_h_
#define A_h_

class A {
  public:
   int a;
   A() { a = 3; }
};

#endif /* A_h_ */
```

> But why is also a C2079 error `'B::myA' uses undefined class 'A'`

As you pointed out without header guards your `Main.cpp` will look something like this:

```
class A { ... }
class A { ... } 
class B { ... }
...
```

which is clearly an error because you defined twice the same class A. From this point on the rest of compilation is kind of pointless, as Main.cpp won't compile, but compiler perhaps ignores altogether errors related to `class A` and tries to compile the rest of the file to show any other possible errors. Because there was two definitions of `class A` it cannot know which one is correct and for that reason perhaps microsoft  compiler treats the rest of compilation as if there was no `class A` defined. That's why you get `'B::myA' uses undefined class 'A'`.

gcc [for example won't report errors](https://ideone.com/U0cWZH) related to use of `class A` and will simply tell you that there was `redefinition of ‘class A’` and will show where previous definition was seen.

Comment: And because class A couldn't be compiled (because of redefinition) the type is not available in B.h, right?

Comment: @knowledge yes, something like that. Because there was an error from that point on it's up to compiler to do whatever. [gcc for example won't continue compilation](https://ideone.com/U0cWZH).

Answer (score 0):

To answer the actual question "But why is [there] also a C2079 error `B::myA` uses undefined class `A` " :

Compilers often try to be helpful and detect more than one error at a time. For that, they have to make a few assumptions about the nature of the first errors. That might not always work out well, and this seems to be one of those cases.
The compiler has continued to compile even though `A` was flagged as problematic, and then tripped over the use of `A`

In hindsight, the error might have been better worded as "'B::myA' uses multiply defined class 'A'".

Comment: IMO, since it was multiply defined it's better to treat as if it wasn't defined, or even better skip errors related to `class A` (that what gcc seems to be doing).

Comment: @Pavel: The problem with that approach can be that the C++ grammar is ambiguous without type information; `A*b` can be a multiplication or a pointer definition. Thus, `b` might not be defined because `A` isn't. Treating `A` as an declared type means that `b` unambiguously is a pointer, even if `A` is only considered declared and not defined.